# C# Why do I need to put "System." before "ConsoleColor" even though I have already "using System;"

Tags: c#

I have put `using System;` at the first line, but when I try to call the `ConsoleColor` in the class method it does not show any color options in the intellisense.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace practice
{
    class ConsoleColor
    {
        public void DisplayColor()
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = System.ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("Hello");
        }
    }
}
```

Fixing this but putting `System.` infront of the `ConsoleColor`.

Wondering why this happen.

Thanks in advance.

**I was so silly, didn't notice the class name..
closed the question.
Thanks so so so much guys....**

Comment: You called your class `ConsoleColor` - how can the compiler know what do you mean when you write just `ConsoleColor` - yours, or the one from the `System` namespace?

Comment: Because the name of your class is *hiding* the System.ConsoleColor type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use `ConsoleColor` as your class name. So to resolve the conflict you have to use `System.` (or change your class's name)

Answer (score 2):

Because your class is called `ConsoleColor`. The compiler doesn't know that you want the  `ConsoleColor` type in the `System` namespace, because it has already found a `ConsoleColor` type.. your class. So you need to state explicitly that you want the type in the `System` namespace.

Comment: No, it can decide just fine.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that Hans?

Comment: It is unambiguous, the compiler will *always* pick his ConsoleColor class, never System.ConsoleColor.

Comment: Thanks. The way I wrote this makes it sound like its an error. I will re-word it. I appreciate your input.

Comment: @HansPassant Hopefully thats a bit better. Again, thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a class `ConsoleColor` which has the same name as the `ConsoleColor` enum.  To resolve this, you have to specify the `System` namespace to tell the compiler to use the `ConsoleColor` enum.  The other option is to rename your class to not collide.